# bootstrap radio button does not respond

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and my radio button click event does not trigger for some reason. I also tried plain javascript method but that does not work either for some reason. So seeking help from

```
  <!-- radio -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputAccountContactAddressZip" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Is billing info same as above? </label>

                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="minimal" value="Yes" onclick="showDiv()" />
                                        Yes
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="minimal" value="No" />
                                        No
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

My javascript looks like so..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showDiv()
    {
    alert("show");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi-ready");
        $('input[type="radio"].minimal').click({
            alert("test")
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In the end there were some compatibility issues between bootstrap template and jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('input.minimal')` for your jquery selector.

Comment: Are you sure this works? The original selector should have worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You modify your jquery click like so :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"].minimal').on
    ("click",function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kodedsoft/09o6ynhv/